# How to root my Nokia XL (updated version)?

Tags: rooting, nokia-xl

An error message is appearing when I'm trying to root my phone by the app frameroot .  I was suggested to use Gandhalf but as my XL is already updated I'm receiving an error message . What do I do ? I wanna update it to the latest android version . But which exploiter should I use ?

Answer (score -1):

you can use the "kingo rot" software for rooting your phone.i have a Nokia XL and use this software for rot

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Mind to [edit] your post and explain *how* exactly this can be achieved – including a link where to find it? Also, as we've got many reports of side-effects caused by Kingoroot (note the double-O, besides ;) it would be welcome if you could point out whether you had any. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I downvoted this answer, but I actually wish I could undo it. If you edit it, I will.